# Editing a vi file using bash script

Tags: bash, redhat

I am doing bash scripting in RHEL7. I managed to do some simple if-else scripting, however, I now need to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config file using bash script. I have to remove the '#' at protocol 2. Is there any way to do this? In addition I would like to add the Protocol 2 line in if it does not exist. I would appreciate any help given.

[image: ssh_config]

Comment: `sed -i 's/^#Protocol 2/Protocol 2/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. Do you mind explaining what does the command mean? For example "sed -i 's/^#", what does that part mean and what does it do?

Comment: `sed ` with `-i` option does replace in the file. `s///` is a standard regular expressions replace command. `^` is indicating the beginning of a line.

Comment: thank you, i understand it now. By the way, is there a way to add in a new line such as 'protocol 2' after a specific line 'the default requires explicit activation of protocol 1' as shown above in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Michel O beat me with `sed -i`, but for more complex edits there is also `ex`, which gives you the power of `vi` from command lines.

Comment: Rather, `vi` provides an interactive shell over the original `ex` editor.

Comment: Well, yes. But I wonder about some implementations, such as gvim.  Anyone know for sure?

Comment: It's not really an implementation of `vi` if it doesn't support `ex`; it would just be an editor with `vi`-style key bindings.